# jdbc CRUD Operations - Getting Null Pointer Exception

Tags: database, servlets, jdbc

I've developed a simple CRUD app. using javabean and getting null pointer exception inUserDao file but can't solve it. Can any one tell me what is the problem ??

this is the code,

User.jsp
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Add New User</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="POST" action='UserHandler' name="frmAddUser"><input type="hidden" name="action" value="insert" />
        <p><b><center>Add New Record<center></b></p>

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Roll Number</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="rollno" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Class</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="clas" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Mobile Number</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="mono" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

        <p><a href="UserHandler?action=listUser">View-All-Records</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

UserHandler.java

```
package handler;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import dao.UserDao;
import bean.UserBean;

public class UserHandler extends HttpServlet    {
    private static String INSERT = "/user.jsp";
    private static String Edit = "/edit.jsp";
    private static String UserRecord = "/listUser.jsp";
    private UserDao dao;

    public UserHandler()    {
        this.dao = new UserDao();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String redirect = "";
        String roll = request.getParameter("rollno");
        String mo = request.getParameter("mono");
        String action = request.getParameter("action");

        if ((roll == null) && (action.equalsIgnoreCase("insert")))  {
            int rollno = Integer.parseInt(roll);
            long mono = Integer.parseInt(mo);
            UserBean user = new UserBean();
            user.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
            user.setRollno(rollno);
            user.setClas(request.getParameter("clas"));
            user.setMono(mono);
            this.dao.addUser(user);
            redirect = UserRecord;
            request.setAttribute("student", this.dao.getAllUsers());
            System.out.println("Record Added Successfully");
        }
        else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")) {
            String roll1 = request.getParameter("rollno");
            int rl = Integer.parseInt(roll1);
            this.dao.removeUser(rl);
            redirect = UserRecord;
            request.setAttribute("student", this.dao.getAllUsers());
            System.out.println("Record Deleted Successfully");
        }
        else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("editform")) {
            redirect = Edit;
        }
        else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("edit")) {
            String roll2 = request.getParameter("rollno");
            String monu = request.getParameter("mobileno");
            int uid = Integer.parseInt(roll2);
            long mono = Integer.parseInt(monu);

            UserBean user = new UserBean();
            user.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
            user.setRollno(uid);
            user.setClas(request.getParameter("clas"));
            user.setMono(mono);
            this.dao.editUser(user);
            request.setAttribute("user", user);
            redirect = UserRecord;
            System.out.println("Record updated Successfully");
        }
        else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("listUser")) {
            redirect = UserRecord;
            request.setAttribute("student", this.dao.getAllUsers());
        }
        else {
            redirect = INSERT;
        }

        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(redirect);
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

UserDao.java

```
package dao;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

import dbconnection.ConnectionProvider;
import bean.UserBean;

public class UserDao    {
    private Connection conn;

    public UserDao()    {
        this.conn = ConnectionProvider.getConnection();
    }

    public void addUser(UserBean userBean) {
        try {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO student (name, rollno, class, mobileno) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ? )";

            PreparedStatement ps = this.conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, userBean.getName());
            ps.setInt(2, userBean.getRollno());
            ps.setString(3, userBean.getClas());
            ps.setLong(4, userBean.getMono());
            ps.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void removeUser(int rollno) {
        try {
            String sql = "DELETE FROM student WHERE rollno=?";

            PreparedStatement ps = this.conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, rollno);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void editUser(UserBean userBean) {
        try {
            String sql = "UPDATE student SET name=?, class=?, mobileno=? WHERE rollno=?";

            PreparedStatement ps = this.conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, userBean.getName());
            ps.setString(2, userBean.getClas());
            ps.setLong(3, userBean.getMono());
            ps.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public List<UserBean> getAllUsers() {
        List student = new ArrayList();
        try {

/*          if(this.conn.isClosed())    {
                System.out.println("Connection is closed");
            }
            else    {
*/          String sql = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE name IS NOT NULL ORDER BY name";
            PreparedStatement ps = this.conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

                while (rs.next()) {
                    UserBean userBean = new UserBean();
                    userBean.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                    userBean.setRollno(rs.getInt("rollno"));
                    userBean.setClas(rs.getString("clas"));
                    userBean.setMono(rs.getLong("mono"));
                    student.add(userBean);
                }
//          }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return student;
    }

    public UserBean getUserById(int rollno) {
        UserBean userBean = new UserBean();
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE rollno=?";

            PreparedStatement ps = this.conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(2, rollno);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                userBean.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                userBean.setRollno(rs.getInt("rollno"));
                userBean.setClas(rs.getString("clas"));
                userBean.setMono(rs.getLong("mono"));
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return userBean;
    }
}
```

this is the error

```
HTTP Status 500 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message 

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

java.lang.NullPointerException
    dao.UserDao.getAllUsers(UserDao.java:69)
    handler.UserHandler.doGet(UserHandler.java:68)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.39 logs.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/7.0.39
```

Comment: What are the contents of your DAO class?

Comment: @PrasadKharkar
Added sir

Comment: It seems multiple variables could be null here, can I see the full stacktrace that is available in tomcat 7 file?

Comment: Also please let us know which is the line number 69 here because we can't see line numbers in this code :(

Comment: something is null at line number 69. may be connection ?

Comment: @vels4j
Line 69
PreparedStatement ps = this.conn.prepareStatement(sql);

Comment: I pasted your code in my eclipse and on line 69, I could see the only problem could be the `conn` object. Make sure you are not getting `null` when initializing `conn = ConnectionProvider.getConnection();`

Comment: are u saying that problem may be in establishing connection ??
Well I am able to run other programs...

Comment: Yes we are implying the same. Only reason we see is that somehow the connection object is being null. Can you check it?

Comment: @PrasadKharkar
may I please know, how ?

Comment: @vels4j
ne suggestion ??

Comment: check this  `public UserDao()    {
        this.conn = ConnectionProvider.getConnection();  System.out.println(conn);
    }`

Comment: @vels4j
it didn't make any difference sir..

Comment: @raman did you try to debug the code? what is the value of `conn` object?

Comment: @PrasadKharkar
thats the problem, I m getting null as a value of connection... it works on others' system. bt not in mine,

Comment: @raman are you sure that your jdbc connection jar is present in WEB-INF/lib? Can you post the code by which you are creating the connection?

Comment: @PrasadKharkar
SIR, I JUST RESTARTED MY SYSTEM AND NOW GETTING Invalid Column Index error..

Comment: It possibly means you are trying to retrieve a column value that haven't been retrieved in resultset. while doing setXXX or getXXX calls, make sure you are passing correct index number. They are not zero based indexes

Comment: @PrasadKharkar

m beginner in Javabeans, so, sorry bt (where )do we have to set index number in it ??

Comment: I didn't mean javabeans...you are calling setInt or setString methods on preparedStatement right? I just mean to say check whether you are setting the values of columns that actually exist in the database tables.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar

Thank you for help Sir, problem is solved but getting another problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589029/geting-no-error-but-data-is-not-updated
can you please help me ??

Answer (score 0):

Create whether connection created successfully or not

```
try {
 String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
 String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:port/db";
 String user = "xx";
 String password = "xxt";
 Class.forName(driver);
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
 System.out.println("Connection"+con);
 } 
 catch(Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Exception when creating connection "+e.getMessage());
 }
```

Comment: Sir, dat problem is solved but now getting 
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name